# Missing periods in second level list

Tags: numbering, lists

I'm working with some multi-level lists, and I've changed the default second level numbering to arabic.  Here's the relevant code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{2}   
    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $P \supset [Q \supset (P \supset R)]$
            \item $P$
            \item $Q \hspace{.75in} / \hspace{.1in} R$
        \end{enumerate}
    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item ${\sim}W \bigcdot {\sim}X$
            \item $Y \supset W$
            \item ${\sim}Y \supset Z \hspace{.75in} / \hspace{.1in} Z \vee X$
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The highest level list from the first enumerate has a period after the number, but the second level, nested lists are missing periods after each number.  Is there a way to force the periods into that second-level enumerate?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))  by adding the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages? Also, where is `\bigcdot` defined?

Comment: Try changing `\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}` to `\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}.}`.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}.}
```

but I'd not overload the `enumerate` environment and would define a new one. With the help of `enumitem` it's quite easy and you don't even need to remember how many items the preceding environment had, if you want to go on with the numbering.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{foo}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[foo]{label=\arabic*.}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\spacebar}{\hspace{0.75in}/\hspace{0.1in}}


\begin{document}

First a \texttt{foo} environment
\begin{foo}
\item A
\item B
\end{foo}
Now another one that goes on with the numbering
\begin{foo}[resume]
    \item 
        \begin{foo}
            \item $P \supset [Q \supset (P \supset R)]$
            \item $P$
            \item $Q \spacebar R$
        \end{foo}
    \item 
        \begin{foo}
            \item ${\sim}W \bigcdot {\sim}X$
            \item $Y \supset W$
            \item ${\sim}Y \supset Z \spacebar Z \vee X$
        \end{foo}
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

Choose a better name than `foo`.

[image]

Since you have several (that is, more than one) occurrence of the construction `\hspace{.75in}/\hspace{.1in}`, it's much better to define a command for it.

I also suggest to avoid `{\sim}` and `\supset`: better define commands for it. The latter should be a `\mathbin` rather than a `\mathrel`, in the context you use it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{foo}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[foo]{label=\arabic*.}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\spacebar}{\hspace{0.75in}/\hspace{0.1in}}
\newcommand{\mnot}{{\sim}}
\newcommand{\mimplies}{\mathbin{\supset}}

\begin{document}

First a \texttt{foo} environment
\begin{foo}
\item A
\item B
\end{foo}
Now another one that goes on with the numbering
\begin{foo}[resume]
    \item 
        \begin{foo}
            \item $P \mimplies [Q \mimplies (P \mimplies R)]$
            \item $P$
            \item $Q \spacebar R$
        \end{foo}
    \item 
        \begin{foo}
            \item $\mnot W \bigcdot \mnot X$
            \item $Y \mimplies W$
            \item $\mnot Y \mimplies Z \spacebar Z \vee X$
        \end{foo}
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the `enumitem` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{2}   
    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
            \item $P \supset [Q \supset (P \supset R)]$
            \item $P$
            \item $Q \hspace{.75in} / \hspace{.1in} R$
        \end{enumerate}
    \item 
        \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]
            \item ${\sim}W \cdot {\sim}X$
            \item $Y \supset W$
            \item ${\sim}Y \supset Z \hspace{.75in} / \hspace{.1in} Z \vee X$
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you think that for the second level `\label*=...` would look  better?